# change ckeditor templates data

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

I want to change the default text of template of creditor.

Following is my ckeditor at time of page load.
[image]

I want to change the **patient name** when user select the patient name from drop down and also want change the drugs section according to drugs added by user from list of drugs.
below is code for CKEDITOR with id prescription_details.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.prescription_details.setData( '<p id="test">Patient Name.</p>' +
        '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%" border="0"><tr><td style="width:60%"><h3>Drugs</h3></td><td></td><td style="width:40%"><h3>Doseage</h3></td></tr></table>' +
        '<p>Instructions.</p>' );
```

and Below is code for takin the value of p with id "test"

```
var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances['prescription_details'].getData("p#test");
```

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: @AlfonsoML:- i added code in question.do needfull help to me

Comment: getData() -> .replace() -> setData() - have you tried this way?

Comment: @HeanzoBeanzo how can i change the content of "p" tag with  id "test"?

Comment: My ckeditor removes the id when i switch from source to wysiwyg and then back again to source view. So I would rather place the html in an hidden div (outside of the editor), load it, replace things, then insert it with setData().

Comment: @HeanzoBeanzo hidden div method working fine. but still i want proper method for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since CKEditor removes the id when you switch from source back to WYSIWYG mode, you have to use a workaround. I could think of two solutions here:

**1. Load content from another source , then insert into CKEditor**

Use a hidden div or an external html file with all the markup and load it into a variable, replace the values, then insert it via `CKEDITOR.instances.prescription_details.setData();`

**2. Don't use id's as selector**

You could useplaceholders:

- Create markup in CKEditor
- Wherever variables are needed, insert placeholders, e.g.: `<p>[DRUGS-CONTENT]</p>`
- Do `.getData()` in order to store text in variable
- [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) placeholders with variables , e.g. `storedText.replace('[DRUGS-CONTENT]', drugsFromUser);`
- Do `.setData()` with replaced text
- Done

Answer (score 0):

editor.getData doesn't take a CSS selector as parameter.

Please, "do needful" and read the documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData

Comment: I read the document it take data in raw format. but how can i take the data for "p" tag only?